# Measure of a cone

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, convex-cone

I hope everyone is going well today.

Is anyone know how to compute the Lebesgue measure of the red cone below ?

[image: The red cone]

Here's more details, I take the ball $B(0,r)$ and the point $q \notin B(0,r)$. Then I take the intersection of this ball with the hyperplan passing through the origin and orthogonal to $q$ that is : $\Sigma_{r} = \{  z \in \mathbb{R}^{n} ; \langle z, q \rangle  = 0 \} \cap B(0,r)$.

Let $C$ be the cone generated by $q$ and $\Sigma_{r}$ we have :
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(C) = c_{n}|q|r^{n-1}
\end{equation}

With $c_{n}>0$ a dimensional constant and $\mathcal{L}$ the Lebesgue measure. 
How to prove that ?

I wish you a very good day.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty obvious. Let $|q|=:h>0$. Then you may assume $q=(0,\ldots,0,h)$ and
$\Sigma_r$ being the ball of radius $r$ in the $x'=(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1})$-plane. The $(n-1)$-volume of this ball is $\kappa_{n-1} r^{n-1}$, where $\kappa_{n-1}$ is the volume of the unit $(n-1)$-ball. The cone $C$ then is a "right circular" cone of height $h$ standing on $\Sigma_r$. A plane $x_n=z\in[0,h]$ intersects $C$ in an $(n-1)$-ball $\Sigma_{\rho(z)}$ of radius $$\rho(z)=r\left(1-{z\over h}\right)\ .$$
Fubini's theorem then gives
$${\rm vol}(C)=\int_C 1\>{\rm d}(x)=\int_0^h\int_{\Sigma_\rho(z)}1\>{\rm d}(x')\>dz=\int_0^h\kappa_{n-1}\rho^{n-1}(z)\>dz=\ldots={\kappa_{n-1}\over n}\>h\>r^{n-1}\ .$$

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for your help. I understood I can use that $\mathcal{C} = C(q,v) := \{ (1-t)q + tu ; t\in[0;1], u \in [B(x,r)\times\{0\} + v] \}$ which has the same Lebesgue measure than $C(q,0)$. Now to apply your proof, we have to show that $C'$ has the same Lebesgue measure than $C(h,0)$. Maybe it exists a orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $AC(q,0) = C(h,0)$ I don't know... I tried... Do you know how to conclude ? I wish you a nice day.

Comment: I meant $C' = C(q,0)$

Comment: Lebesgue measure is invariant under isometries, resp., does not depend on the chosen orthonormal basis. We then can choose a basis with $e_n\parallel q$.

Comment: Indeed, I beg your pardon how to apply it ? For exemple, if I try $PC(q,0)$ then $q$ become $h$ but it is not a cone anymore. For exemple, $P(B(x,r)\times\{0\})$ not need to be ball.

Comment: I think we are about to conclude. I just need to prove that $|C(q,0)| = |C(h,0)|. Write a rigourous proof it is not totally obious for me.

Comment: Okay... Never mind thank you for your help sir. It was a honor.